# Datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to create a method in javascript which will take parameters as

- DateRange (possible values as 'Today'/'This Week'/'This Month'
- BooleanFullDate (possible values as true/false)

Now, When parameter value is `Today` it should return me

```
10/23/2013 
10/23/2013
```

When `This Week` and BooleanFullDate as `true`, then it should return me

```
10/20/2013
10/26/2013
```

When `This Week` and BooleanFullDate as `false`, then it should return me

```
10/20/2013
10/23/2013
```

When `This Month` and BooleanFullDate as `true`, then it should return me

```
10/01/2013
10/31/2013
```

When `This Month` and BooleanFullDate as `false`, then it should return me

```
10/01/2013
10/23/2013
```

For which I have written my code as here - [**JS Fiddle LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/PSW9T/25/)

Issue:-

Now, Being very new to javascript I am unable to figure out few things(which you can see in the jsbin also)

When I am calling `GetStartAndEnd("Today");` why is it returning me `end: "9/23/2013",` and not `end: "10/23/2013",` (Current Month) ?

Lastly, please can someone suggest me improvement of the code?

Comment: javascript getMonth() Returns the month (from 0-11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I am calling GetStartAndEnd("Today"); why is it returning me end:
>   "9/23/2013", and not end: "10/23/2013", (Current Month) ?

Well,

> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the
>   specified date, according to local time.

So you have to add +1 to your `getMonth()`

means:

```
var lmonth = lastDay.getMonth() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used     `var month = dateobj.getMonth()` . In this function January always starts from 0. So you'll have to add 1 in the returned value of getMonth() which will give you the exact current month.